# Unexpected output while printing a linked list

Tags: c, ubuntu, data-structures, linked-list, codeblocks

I got this code on codeblocks 13.12 in lubuntu 16.04

The program is running but the problem is that **the first insertion is duplicated** that is,

lets say i first insert integer "4" to the linked list. But i get the output as:

`4 ,4 ,`

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
   struct node* next;
};

struct node* head = NULL;

void Insert(int c)
{
if(head == NULL) {
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp -> data = c;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    head = temp;
}

struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp -> data = c;
temp -> next = NULL;
struct node* temp1 = head;

    while (temp1->next != NULL) {
        temp1 = temp1->next;

}
temp1 -> next = temp;
    }


void print() {

    struct node* temp = head;
    printf("list is: \n");
    while (temp != NULL) {

        printf( "%d ,",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}


int main () {

printf("How Many Numbers?\n");
int a ,b ,c;
scanf("%d" , &b);
for(a = 0;a<b;a++) {
    printf("Enter the numbers \n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    Insert(c);
    print();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always check the return value of functions, in this case `scanf()` which returns the number of successful assignments made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem is that the first insertion is duplicated

**Reason:**

- **You've mentioned `if(head==NULL)` correctly to check whether inserted node is first node or not** but after this you did not mention **else** to restrict compiler.
- So the compiler compiles both the if block and the code following it
- So another node gets created after `head` with the same value `c`
- that's the reason when you insert `c=4`, you get `4,4,` as output

---

**Solution**

Try using your `insert()` with an **else** condition as

```
void Insert(int c)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp -> data = c;
        temp -> next = NULL;
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp -> data = c;
        temp -> next = NULL;
        struct node* temp1 = head;
        while (temp1->next!= NULL)
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        temp1 -> next = temp;
     }
}
```

---

**suggestion** : *you've mentioned this twice in you `insert()` function*

```
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp -> data = c;
    temp -> next = NULL;
```

just allocate `temp` once and then insert it at approprite position using `if-else` conditions. This reduces the number of lines of code too. do it this way:

```
void Insert(int c)
{
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp -> data = c;
    temp -> next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* temp1 = head;
        while (temp1->next!= NULL)
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        temp1 -> next = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is accepted answer but there is a mistake: `temp1 -> next = temp;` should not be inside the `while` loop.

Comment: oh yeah @WeatherVane i'll update. thanks for the mention... that's reason i don't use curly braces to the right of loops... they easily get camouflaged :) , so i prefer write them in a new line or avoid them if possible

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `Insert` function "falls through" after initialising the first item, and inserts it again. Add `return` at the end of the code block.

```
void Insert(int c)
{
if(head == NULL) {
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp -> data = c;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    return;        //<-- add this line
}
...
```